# Grails Spring jar dependency with Atmosphere plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, atmosphere

I am running into dependency issues with with Atmosphere plugin.
I am using grails 2.3.6 but getting following error on server start up

```
2014-04-20 01:21:44,262 [localhost-startStop-1] 
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Message: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRef
resh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/
Class;)Z
```

To me it seems to be dependency problem, but I am unable to pin point which specific jar/s
I ran over dependency report but couldn't make out where is the real issue.

Any idea ??

Comment: Which version of the plugin is used?

Comment: Have you tried excluding `spring-beans` from the plugin?

Comment: compile ":jms:1.3"
compile ":atmosphere-meteor:0.8.3"

Can you explain what do you mean by 'excluding spring-beans' ??

Comment: [Excluding specific transitive dependency](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies). I meant excluding `spring-beans` transitive dependency from plugin

Comment: Removing 'spring-beans' results in classnot found errors .NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/SpringProperties

Comment: Entry in dependency closure
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.5.1',
                  'org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:3.1.3',
                  'org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE',
                  'org.springframework:spring-jms:3.2.4.RELEASE',
                  'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.2') {
                excludes 'activemq-openwire-generator'
                excludes 'commons-logging'
                excludes 'xalan' 
                excludes 'xml-apis'
                exported = false
              }